# Must find a users but how many antale

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working right now to build LINQ up to the side where it needs to retrieve some information from the user about how many applications as you have got to be friends. - *user exists in tablen.*

```
venner Numberoffriends = db.venners.Where(UseridFriends => UseridFriends.To == 1 && UseridFriends.Godkendt == 0).Count();
    if(Numberoffriends != null)
    {
    //true 
    }
```

it is such that it now makes mistakes here

```
db.venners.Where(UseridFriends => UseridFriends.To == 1 && UseridFriends.Godkendt == 0).Count();
```

ERROR ARE: **The type 'int' can not be implicitly converted to 'LinqData.venner'**

Comment: *what* mistakes are being made?

Comment: ohh sorry i have not add its error **The type 'int' can not be implicitly converted to 'LinqData.venner'**

Comment: Your error was very helpful and I immediately realised what you were doing wrong - if my answer is helpful to you would you mind accepting it? If not, could you give some more details so that I can try to help you more?

Comment: @JesperPetersen you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29783238/edit) your error message in to your question. A suggestion: don't add a bold **UPDATE** or **EDIT** or similar - just write it as if you wrote the question for the first time. It makes for a cleaner question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the return type of the [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038) extension method is `int`, and you are trying to assign the return value to a `LinqData.venner`.

There is no [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2) from `int` to `LinqData.venner`, so that is the source of your error.

You can confirm this by refactoring your code into the following equivalent code:

```
int count = db.venners.Where(UseridFriends => UseridFriends.To == 1 && UseridFriends.Godkendt == 0).Count();
venner Numberoffriends = count;
if ( Numberoffriends != null )
{
    //true 
}
```

which will transfer your compilation error to the

```
venner Numberoffriends = count;
```

line.

---

It seems from your code that instead of having a count (using the `Count()` method), you want something like [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482) or [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261). This will enable you to *do* something with the `venner` object(s) you get.

I think the following would build, but I'm not sure about your intention and hence if it's what you *want*:

```
List<venner> venners = db.venners
    .Where(UseridFriends => UseridFriends.To == 1 && UseridFriends.Godkendt == 0)
    .ToList();

if ( venners.Count != 0 )
{
    //true 
    // do something with venners here
}
```

What are you trying to *do* with your linq?

Comment: You can add a `ToList()` and can call `Count()` on the result of the `Where()` so that all possible questions are answered.

Comment: @MareInfinitus - True. Or even just use the `Count` property. I also wanted to put in my answer that you can put a predicate in `FirstOrDefault` and `Count` but decided against it because I didn't want to confuse matters.

Comment: @JesperPetersen — Many apologies. I have corrected an error in what I posted - I was assigning the wrong type to `venners`. It was `venner venners = db.venners....` but is now `List<venner> venners = db.venners...`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @WaiHaLee How will I be able to order it on some text ?, I no errors now. :)

Comment: @WaiHaLee I think about it to print it to label as here `LabelVen.Text = //What should I add here`